# or-tools single driver first solution problem

Tags: or-tools

In my application I have a single driver and many vehicles. i.e, he can drive the next vehicle after the end of the previous trip
in term of constraint it is something like

```
routing.solver().AddConstraint(
                             time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.End(int(pre_vehicle_id))) <=
                             time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.Start(int(vehicle_id)))
                        )
```

after many tries I found that such constraint works only if I set the first solution strategy to PARALLEL_CHEAPEST_INSERTION.

Here, I have some problems:

- sometimes it failed with no reason, or it takes very long time to get the first solution.
  is it a bug? or I do something wrong. What is the correct way to implement such constraint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The routing solver is trying its utmost to build parallel routes with different drivers.
You extra constraint is just breaking all feasible routes the solver is building, thus the hard time finding feasible solutions.

To solve your problem, you need to have only one driver (vehicle in the routing API).

One vehicle is not enough to visit all nodes because of the capacity limit. You need to get inspiration from the [reload model](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/constraint_solver/samples/cvrp_reload.py) where a reload at a copy of the initial node corresponds to a vehicle change.

Comment: Thanks for replay. I was finally able to implement your suggestion. other problems appeared in the new implementation, one of them that the solution use them too much more than necessary. Is there a trick to add penalty for visiting them, (not for dropping)